# This program may change the definition of setinterval or maybe not

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mern

Here `a == 3` and the condition was true but when the `setinterval` runs, the value of `a` will be `4` then, `do while` will check the condition and it will be a false condition, though this will not run.

I don't see any error in this.

`setinterval` was blocking the next condition which will be verified but it's an infinite loop which does not end so the checking of condition will not happen but do while was executed first without checking the condition and the inside if condition was true will execute the `setinterval` method but the confusion created in the definition of asynchronous function definition is that (it will be multi-threaded so the execution of both will run simultaneously it will hold the execution `setinterval` and execute the upcoming statements) by following the definition it will check condition first but this will prove wrong the definition of `do while` loop because in `do while` the condition was checked in 2nd iteration 1st iteration will be executed without checking the condition of the loop.

```
var a=3;

function ali() {
  console.log("testing and understanding setInterval method");
  a++;
}

do {
  if (a == 3)
    setInterval(ali,1000);
} while (a == 3);
```

`setInterval` should run but being on asynchronous function it is running with no output. When running it it says *heap stack is full* in Node.js.

Comment: Javascript runs in one thread.  `setInterval`s callback will not run, because `do...while` loop is blocking it

Comment: The function `ali` will only be executed by `setInterval` 1 second **after your script ends**. Since your script **never ends** javascript never gets the chance to process `setInterval` callbacks and therefore `ali` **never gets executed**.

Comment: still i dont get it . i programmed it just for understanding the asyncronous nature

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is **not** multi-threaded.  You essentially have:

```
condition = true;
do {
  setInterval(some_function_that_changes_condition, 1000)
} while(condition);
```

You're right that this is an infinite loop.

This is like saying ***"I will continuously order pizzas until one arrives"***.  So you start ordering pizza-after-pizza on the phone but you ***never answer the door*** when one of the pizzas actually arrives ***because you're busy making phone-calls*** to order more pizzas.

`setInterval` basically schedules a function to be run later, but nothing else can happen in JavaScript until you relinquish control of the JavaScript context by returning from the function that this code was written in.  There is no way for JavaScript to interrupt execution of your loop to execute the callback.  Maybe you're thinking that it might happen during one of the `setInterval` calls?  But it won't.

In Node.js the timer may very well be scheduled and the thread that wants to invoke the callback function may be runnable, but the JavaScript engine itself is busy running your infinite loop and cannot be interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

The timer functions never guarantee that they would run precisely after the interval. It literally says that "I will execute it soon as I get the breathing space after the specified time".

What is breathing space? Every time a function runs, the JS engine waits for the function to return. This is the breathing space. It is at that moment the JS engine checks its "Event Loop" what it has to execute next. This is the only time your timer function may be scheduled to run.

The timer never runs before the long loop is over in the following example.

```js
function test()  {

  console.log('Starting')
  
  setTimeout(()=> console.log('timer executed'), 1000)
  
  for (let i=1; i<=9999999999; i++);
  
  console.log('the loop is over');
  

}

test()
```